# Can I connect 2 LAN Cards, and get 2 IPs, then use them in web server (nginx)

Tags: dhcp, nginx, router

I'm having deal with Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS. So the question is - can I buy second LAN card, and get 2 ip addresses? Will it work, and can I use them with NGINX?